# What is logic and wrong behind this function command?

Tags: r, statistics

I have to set default value of 5000 to d. I am using this argument

```
Rfun <- function(d : 5000){
storage=c()
for(i in seq(0,40,2){
d <- d/(1.035^i)
storage <- append(storage,d)
}
storage
}.
```

Please someone help with logic behind it as well.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. I assume that you want: `function(d = 5000)` instead of `function(d : 5000)`. Not really sure where the colon comes from.

Comment: There is also a bracket missing in the `for(...)` line. Finally, growing a vector dynamically is usually a bad idea in R. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your function much more succinctly using `cumprod`

```
Rfun2 <- function(d = 5000) d * cumprod(1 / (1.035 ^ seq(0, 40, 2)))
Rfun2(d = 2)
#[1] 2.000000e+00 1.867021e+00 1.627001e+00 1.323567e+00 1.005132e+00
#[6] 7.125568e-01 4.715582e-01 2.913201e-01 1.680060e-01 9.044791e-02
#[11] 4.545603e-02 2.132573e-02 9.339754e-03 3.818443e-03 1.457325e-03
#[16] 5.192136e-04 1.726851e-04 5.361459e-05 1.553926e-05 4.204333e-06
#[21] 1.061899e-06
```

Not only does `Rfun2` avoid the explicit `for` loop, but we also avoid growing a `vector` dynamically with `append` (for which there is almost always a better vectorised alternative in R).

Let's compare this with your original function (fixing the syntax errors pointed out in the comments above)

```
Rfun <- function(d = 5000){
    storage <- c()
    for(i in seq(0,40,2)) {
        d <- d/(1.035^i)
        storage <- append(storage,d)
    }
    storage
}
Rfun(d = 2)
#[1] 2.000000e+00 1.867021e+00 1.627001e+00 1.323567e+00 1.005132e+00
#[6] 7.125568e-01 4.715582e-01 2.913201e-01 1.680060e-01 9.044791e-02
#[11] 4.545603e-02 2.132573e-02 9.339754e-03 3.818443e-03 1.457325e-03
#[16] 5.192136e-04 1.726851e-04 5.361459e-05 1.553926e-05 4.204333e-06
#[21] 1.061899e-06
```

We confirm that `Rfun` and `Rfun2` give the same results.